# Using if-else to order program to do one or another sequence of actions

Tags: python, model, arcgis, arcpy

I'm a beginner in Python. Actually, I'm using arcpy together with ArcGIS and Model Builder for my studies.

How would the script look like if I need the model to check the extension of the file (it's either .shp or .gpx) and let the model run one sequence of geoprocessing or another sequence? I'm trying to type `if`-`else` code and find a way, but without luck so far.

You can also read [my question in GIS stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280206/check-file-extension-in-modelbuilder-or-python-script-tool), where I got too little help to continue with.

I also found in on of the topics part of a short code like this:

```
from glob import glob...
for files in glob('path/*.mp3'): 
  do something
for files in glob('path/*.flac'): 
  do something else
```

Would something like this help? How would the full code look like?

Thanks a lot in advance, I'm really stuck with this!

Comment: That should work if you change `.mp3` and `.flac` to `.shp` and `.gpx`, which confuses me, since now I don't understand what your actual question is :)

Comment: Yes, correct, I didnt change the file extension names from the example to match my problem. However, my question is a bit different... what do I write in "do something" line? How to tell the model that I need it to do some sort of geoprocessing sequence? Can you give an example? I for example need it to say that if its .shp file, then run "Select Layer by Location" and join this file to the "Add Surface Information" tool. So how do I write it in python?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if.. elif...` seems to be what you need (and should probably have tried already). Your code could like this:

```
extension = file.split(".")[-1]

if extension == "shp":
  # do shp stuff
elif extension == "gpx":
  # do gpx stuff
else:
  raise ValueError("Only files with the extension '.gpx' or '.shp` can be handled")
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is exactly what im trying. But Im not sure how to script the lines after if and elif ? like where you wrote # do shp stuff... so could you give an example what could be written there? how do I order a model to use a concrete model tool? Ive never used Model Builder with programming...